# How do you plot by Groupby?

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I want to know how to plot a bar graph among groups 'new_build', X Axis shows the towns and Y Axis shows the percentage values from the calculation performed in the code below

```
  df_House.groupby(['new_build', 'town'])['price_paid'].count()/df_House.groupby(['new_build', 'town'])['price_paid'].count().sum()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

data = [['a', 'x', 100], ['b', 'y', 200], ['c', 'z', 300], ['a', 'y', 400], ['b', 'z', 600], ['c', 'x', 100]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['new_build', 'town', 'price_paid'])

df_town = df.groupby(['new_build', 'town']).agg({'price_paid': 'sum'})
new_df = df_town.div(state, level='new_build') * 100
new_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

sns.set()
new_df.set_index(['new_build', 'town']).price_paid.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
plt.ylabel('% of price_paid')
```

[image]

Not sure if you need a stacked graph to better represent the data but to keep things less complicated, I have created a bar graph performing the task you requested.